# Give link to a movieclip to external url in flash actionscript 3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4, movieclip

I wanna link a movie clip which has instace name test1 to a external url (example: http://www.google.com)

I am using a menu list which has main movieclip instance name as 'Primary_Menu'. And inside this main movie clip there are 7 menus (home, about us etc..) each menus are movie clip and has instance names.
Below code is written for linking them to respective frames. but i need to give external url for last menu (test1)

```
    Home_MC.logo_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ShowHome);
    Home_MC.Primary_Menu.pmenu_btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ShowHome);
    Home_MC.Primary_Menu.pmenu_btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ShowLocation);
    Home_MC.Primary_Menu.pmenu_btn3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ShowMasterplan);
    Home_MC.Primary_Menu.pmenu_btn4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ShowDesigner);
    Home_MC.Primary_Menu.pmenu_btn5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ShowAmenities);
    Home_MC.Primary_Menu.pmenu_btn6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ShowDevelopment);
    Home_MC.Primary_Menu.pmenu_btn7.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ShowContact);
    Home_MC.Primary_Menu.pmenu_btn8.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ShowLiving);
    Home_MC.Primary_Menu.test1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,need to got to url here);
```

Please suggest!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for( var i:uint = 1;i< 10; i++)
{
    Home_MC.Primary_Menu["pmenu_btn"+i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, action);
}
function action(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    switch(e.target.name){
        case "pmenu_btn9":
                //do action
                  navigateToURL(new URLRequest("url link"));
                break;
                default:
                break;
    }
}
```

rename `pmenu_btn9` instead of test1. and then run.

Comment: No thats not working. already i have menu till pmenu_btn9 so i need to give diffecrent instant name for new menu and link it to external url.. new link is also in the same path (Home_MC.Primary_Menu.newlink)

Comment: Check whether the `CLICK` handler target the mc or not?